# Create a different local database for different users in chat app

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have created a chat app with a local database to store users' messages. But when I logged out and logged in with a different user, the old message data still exists. I don't want to clear that data in case the user logged back in since these messages are not backed up in the server. So how do I make a different database for another user?

```
_createChatTable(Database db) async {
    await db
        .execute(
          """CREATE TABLE chats(
            id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            username TEXT NOT NULL,
            unread INTEGER,
            message_type TEXT,
            created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
            )""",
        )
        .then((_) => print('creating table chats...'))
        .catchError((e) => print('error creating chats table: $e'));
  }
```

This is the function that currently creates the database.

Comment: use same db, but use a add a field login_user_id to save messages and always filter messages by checking condition with login_user_id. never clear the db

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sqflite.
You can just open another db file, no?

```
_db = await openDatabase(filePath, version: version, onCreate: _onCreate);
```